# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm getting error in this code, I'm trying to do an event where in when the page is load, it will do the event. But the problem is when I go to other function, but same page, it gets a error of null on that variable. It has no problem when I execute this code, but when I'm on other part of my code this error occurs.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      
      
      var str = document.getElementById("cal_preview").value;
      var str1 = document.getElementById("year").value;
      var str2 = document.getElementById("holiday").value;
      var str3 = document.getElementById("cal_option").value;
   

        if (str=="" && str1=="" && str2=="" && str3=="" )
          {
            document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML="";
              return;
            } 
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
              {
                document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
              }
          }
          
        var url = calendar_preview_vars.plugin_url + "?id=" + str +"&"+"y="+str1+"&"+"h="+str2+"&"+"opt="+str3;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 
    

 });
```

Comment: where is your "calendar_preview_vars" ?

Comment: Please post your accompanying HTML

Comment: you sure the elements with first four ids exist? put a `debugger;` statement in your ready function and see which line throws error.

Comment: They do exist, it has no problem when this function is called, but when you are on other function, this is the time that it has error.

Comment: If [*document.getElementById*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) can't find an element with the supplied ID, it returns *null*. So the error is telling you it can't find one of the elements by ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I am unsure *which* of them is wrong because you did not provide your HTML, but one of these does not exist:

```
var str = document.getElementById("cal_preview").value;
var str1 = document.getElementById("year").value;
var str2 = document.getElementById("holiday").value;
var str3 = document.getElementById("cal_option").value;
```

There is either no element with the id `cal_preview`, `year`, `holiday`, `cal_option`, or some combination.

Therefore, JavaScript is unable to read the value of something that does not exist.

**EDIT**:

If you want to check that the element exists first, you could use an if statement for each:

```
var str,
element = document.getElementById('cal_preview');
if (element != null) {
    str = element.value;
}
else {
    str = null;
}
```

You could obviously change the else statement if you want or have no else statement at all, but that is all about preference.

Comment: I think your getting my point, I tried to put a validation there like if null, but did not work. Is it possible to verify if value exist or not? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: You want to just check if it exists and do nothing if it does not or try to figure out which one it thinks does not exist?

Comment: I want to check if all of them exist, if not skip the process.

Comment: the error now is on this part  document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;,. cannot set property innerhtml of null

Comment: Just simply do exactly the same that you did on the previous.  Also, if you want, you could just skip everything if one of them does not exist.

Comment: I would need to see the new JavaScript (and preferably HTML) to find the problem.

Comment: The problem is that, the calendar_preview is on other content, so when then the other content is called the error occurs. But all of the contents are on the same document. But they are called differently. :(

Comment: I am not really sure but maybe you are checking before you actually include the other content.

Comment: Hey Men I figured it out. I did what you told me and then it has error on innerhtml. and then i added this if(document.getElementById("calendar_preview") != null) {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                  document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            } and it works. I hope they remove downvote for this thread thx :)

Comment: Thank you everyone! I was going crazy in figuring out why my code below the .value lines wouldn't execute. I had to open the "inspect" frame within chrome to see the error. What i cannot understand is, why does the browser not show some error? The javascript code seems to error and exit in the background, but there's no visible indication of this (atleast in chrome, unless Inspect it turned ON)

Comment: @electronicsguy All JavaScript errors are shown in the console. No information is shown outside of the console about whether or not JavaScript is working because it wouldn't really be useful to anyone except a developer, who is expected to open the console to fix errors.

Answer (score 16):

Easier and more succinct with `||`:

```
  var str = ((document.getElementById("cal_preview")||{}).value)||"";
  var str1 = ((document.getElementById("year")||{}).value)||"";
  var str2 = ((document.getElementById("holiday")||{}).value)||"";
  var str3 = ((document.getElementById("cal_option")||{}).value)||"";


    if (str=="" && str1=="" && str2=="" && str3=="" )
      {
        document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML="";
          return;
        } 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
            document.getElementById("calendar_preview").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
      }

    var url = calendar_preview_vars.plugin_url + "?id=" + str +"&"+"y="+str1+"&"+"h="+str2+"&"+"opt="+str3;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 8):

My mistake was that I was keeping the Javascript file ( tag) above the html declaration.

It worked by placing the js script tag at the bottom of the body inside the body. (I did not the script on load of the page.)

Answer (score 6):

Add a check

```
if (document.getElementById('cal_preview') != null) {
    str = document.getElementById("cal_preview").value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If in your **HTML** you have an input element with a **name** or **id** with a **_** like e.g. **first_name** or more than one **_** like e.g. **student_first_name** and you also have the Javascript code at the bottom of your Web Page and you are sure you are doing everything else right, then those dashes could be what is messing you up.

Having **id** or **name** for your input elements resembling the below

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name">
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="student_first_name" name="student_first_name">
```

Then you try make a call like this below in your **JavaScript** code

```
var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
```

or

```
var student_first_name = document.getElementById("student_first_name").value;
```

You are certainly going to have an error like ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null*** in **Google Chrome** and on **Internet Explorer** too. I did not get to test that with Firefox.

In my case I removed the dashes, in **first_name** and renamed it to **firstname** and from **student_first_name** to **studentfirstname**

At the end, I was able to resolve that error with my code now looking as follows for HTML and JavaScript.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="studentfirstname" name="studentfirstname">
```

**Javascript**

```
var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
```

or

```
var studentfirstname = document.getElementById("studentfirstname").value;
```

So if it is within your means to rename the **HTML** and **JavaScript** code with those dashes, it may help if that is what is ailing your piece of code. In my case that was what was bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of document or $(document) to avoid JQuery, you can add a TimeOut to validate the objects. TimeOut is executed after loading all objects within the page and other events...

```
setTimeout(function () { 

var str = document.getElementById("cal_preview").value;
var str1 = document.getElementById("year").value;
....
....
....

}, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

handle through try catch

```
    try {
      Block of code to try
    }
    catch(err) {
      Block of code to handle errors
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add `MainContent_` to ID value.

Example:

This will produce an error

```
document.getElementById("Password").value = text;
```

This will work OK:

```
document.getElementById("**MainContent_**Password").value = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML : Pass the whole body inside on click

```
div class="calculate" id="calculate">
            <div class="button" id="button" onclick="myCode(this.body)"> CALCULATE ! </div>
        </div>
```

Then write the JavaScript code inside the function "myCode()"

```
function myCode()
{
    var bill = document.getElementById("currency").value ;

    var people_count = document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var select_value = document.getElementById("select").value;

    var calculate = document.getElementById("calculate");

    calculate.addEventListener("click" ,function()
    {
        console.log(bill);
        console.log(people_count);
        console.log(select_value);
    });
}
```

you will get your values
I am using visual studio code editor

Answer (score -1):

check for the script tag - it should be bellow the body content and above the body tag

```html
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```