# How to give incremental coordinates to CSS elements with DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, setinterval

I'm a newbie in `JS` and in Web Dev altogether. I came across this problem:

Got a cat and mouse done in `CSS` and `HTML`. What I'm trying to achieve is to move the cat by increments on the `Y axis` so that it is positioned on the same level as the mouse, giving  the impression that the cat is not jumping on the mouse straight away.

It will eventually, but for the time being, I'd like the cat to move from `100 top` to `300 top` and then from `300 top` to `600 top` which is the coordinate of the mouse on the `Y axis`. Here's my `js` file , but it doesn't seem to work out, the cat goes to `300 top` and just sits there, so I thought I should seek for help on Stack with you guys :-).

Can you help anyone? Thx

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const $cat = document.querySelector("#cat");

  setInterval(() => {
    var currentPosition = $cat.style.top;
    var newPosition;
    var direction = 200;
    if (currentPosition <= 100) {
      direction = 200;
    } else if (currentPosition <= 300) {
      direction = 300;
    }
    newPosition = currentPosition + direction;
    $cat.style.top = newPosition + "px";
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: so your logic is correct but when you get `$cat.style.top;` after one second it will return `"300px"` which is correct Hihi... now `else if (currentPosition <= 300)` will resolve to false since `currentPosition` is a String. `newPosition` will then be set to `"300px200px" ` which is bullocks so this explains it

Comment: oh a neat trick is if you have a "velocity" that you add to the mouse's and the cat's position where the cats velocity is increase by lets say 2 and set to this new value which will give the impression that the cat accelerates

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and cleaned up. The problem was `$cat.style.top` is a string and you tried to add a string which concatenates them. Which then resulted in unrecognized css properties, so the Item was stuck.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

    const cat = document.querySelector("#cat");
    const regEx = /\d+/ // matches all digits
    let direction, currentPosition = 0;


    setInterval(() => {

        currentPosition = regEx.exec(cat.style.top)[0]

        if (currentPosition <= 100) {
            direction = 200;
        } else if (currentPosition <= 300) {
            direction = 300;
        } else {
            console.error(`skipped if statements oO`)
        }
        cat.style.top = (currentPosition + direction) + "px";

    }, 1000);
});
```

for all those who fear regEx there's a `String.substring()` function which also can be used to get rid of the px part at the end of `cat.style.top`

Comment: Hi fubar, thanks for the warm welcome, I appreciate. I tried the code you advised, but I got an 'uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '100' of null' message on the console. Any idea ?

Comment: So the message says that you are trying to access a property "100" from a variable that is null. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057610/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null) that addresses this issue