# How to export a Cytoscape.js graph to image?

Tags: javascript, console.log, cytoscape.js

I am learning Cytoscape.js. I successfully make a HTML file containing [this basic graph](https://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/specifying-basic-options). I try to export the graph to image using:

```js
var png64 = cy.png();

// put the png data in an img tag
document.querySelector('#png-eg').setAttribute('src', png64);)
```

and get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:1
debugger eval code:1:10
```

There is this post [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22057610/3416774) but I don't understand it. I suspect it's simply that there is no declared element with id `#png-eg`. But when I replace that with other declared elements with id –  which are `cy` (to display the graph), `a`, `b`, `ab` (the nodes and edge) – the only element that doesn't yield the error is `cy`. But even then I don't know where the image locates.

I tried add this element `<img id="png-eg" src="">` in the body, but it still doesn't work. The null error still happens. (But if I don't include the `cy.png()` in the script but type in the console, the error is `Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character`).

In the example there is a line `window.cy`, so I try to run that in the console. I get `Object { _private: {…} }`

[image]

Comment: Is this run in Node.js or the browser?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev browser

Comment: I'm quite new to JS though. There isn't any declared element of id `#png-eg`, but I assume it will be made from the script? The declared elements with id are `cy` (to display the graph), `a`, `b`, `ab` (the nodes and edge). The only element that doesn't yield the error is `cy`, but even then I don't know where the image locates

Comment: I don't think the `img` element is created by Cytoscape. As far as I remember, I had to manually create it and insert it in the DOM.

Comment: do you mean I should make this element `<img id="png-eg" src="">` in the body? I tried but it still doesn't work. The null error still happens. (But if I don't include the `cy.png()` in the script but type in the console, the error is `Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the following (make sure the DOM is loaded before trying to query for elements):

HTML:

```html
<div id="cy"></div>

<button>Render PNG</button>
```

CSS:

```css
#cy {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

JS:

```js
const cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  // and the rest of the example you already have
})

const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const base64URI = cy.png();
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = base64URI;

  document.body.appendChild(img);
});
```

This will create a new image element and make its source equal to the base64   PNG representation exported by Cytoscape. Then the element will be added to the DOM and you can see the snapshot of the graph rendered inside the image tag.

You can see the whole example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-4qqj1o?file=index.js).

Comment: thanks. For studying purpose, I try to cut a line by using `const img = document.createElement('img').setAttribute('src', base64URI);`, but it doesn't work. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Because `.setAttribute()` returns nothing (void). This means the value assigned to `img` will be `undefined` instead of the actual image element.

Comment: but why does it return nothing? If that's the case, then `img.setAttribute('src', base64URI);` wouldn't work, which it is. It's also the same with `img.src = base64URI;`

Comment: `.setAttribute()` mutates the object it's called on but has no return value itself. When you try to assign its result to a variable, the variable will equal `undefined`. In this case, what will actually get evaluated is `const img =undefined`. The actual element will be created, its `src` attribute changed, but you will lose the reference to it.