# How do I set the URL of a hyperlink to a js variable?

Tags: javascript

I need help with setting urls to JS variables,

```html
<input id="urlbox"><a href="main.htm" target=main id=gourl><button>Go</button></a>
<script>
  var urlgo = document.getElementById('gourl');
  var seturl = document.getElementById('urlbox').value;
  setInterval(function() {
  urlgo.setAttribute('href', seturl);
}, 300);
</script>
```

It doesn't work in any internet browser I tested it in, how do I get it to work?
The behavior I expected is that every 0.3 seconds, the url of the go button is set to the value of the text box, but nothing happens when i use it, does anyone know how to make it work?
If it helps, I don't get an error, but the url just gets set to blank no matter what I enter

Comment: Remove the `.` before the `;`.

Comment: Though your code will probably not work, `getElementById` will return `null` because the script tag is loaded before the HTML. Move the script tag to the end of your code.

Comment: I replaced .; with ; and it still doesn't work, i put the script after the input and button and it just makes the url nav.htm

Comment: you can add the defer attribute to the script tag or put it at the very end inside your body.

Comment: Duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057610/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null)

Comment: btw, you cannot put an href in an input like this. Inputs value is set via the value attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the

```
var urlgo = document.getElementById('gourl');
var seturl = document.getElementById('urlbox').value;
```

inside the the setInterval.