# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox

I have been trying to integrate PayPal in my e-commerce project. It works fine in Paypal button but I have problems in making the transaction complete.

After clicking "Pay Now" in the sandbox, the money goes through but the transaction in my database was not completed.

Here's my `checkout.html` file:

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element" id="form-wrapper">
                <form id="form">
                    <div id="user-info">
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input required class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="shipping-info">
                        <hr>
                        <p>Shipping Information:</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" placeholder="State..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zip" placeholder="zip code..">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Continue">
                </form>
            </div>

            <br>
            <div class="box-element hidden" id="payment-info">
                <small>Paypal Options</small>

                <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
            </div>
            
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element">
                <a  class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'cart' %}">&#x2190; Back to Cart</a>
                <hr>
                <h3>Order Summary</h3>
                <hr>
                {% for item in items %}
                    <div class="cart-row">
                        <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
                        <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
                        <div style="flex:1"><p>₱{{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                        <div style="flex:1"><p>x{{item.quantity}}</p></div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <h5>Items:   {{order.get_cart_items}}</h5>
                <h5>Total:   ₱{{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD"></script>

<script>
    var total = '{{order.get_cart_total}}'
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        style:{
            //color: 'blue',
            shape: 'rect',
        },

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                submitFormData()
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var shipping = '{{order.shipping}}'
    var user = '{{request.user.is_authenticated}}'
    

    if(shipping == 'False'){
        document.getElementById('shipping-info').innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (user != "False"){
        document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (shipping == 'False' && user != "False"){
        //Hide entire form if user is logged in and shipping is false
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper').classList.add('hidden');
        //Show payment if logged in user wants to buy an item that does not require shipping
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove('hidden');
    }

    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Form Submitted...')
        document.getElementById('form-button').classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove("hidden");
    })

    /*document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        submitFormData()
    })
    */

    function submitFormData(){
        console.log('Payment button clicked')

        var userFormData = {
            'name':null,
            'email':null,
            'total':total,
        }

        var shippingInfo = {
            'address':null,
            'city':null,
            'state':null,
            'zip':null,
        }

        if (shipping != 'False'){
            shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
            shippingInfo.city = form.city.value
            shippingInfo.state = form.state.value
            shippingInfo.zip = form.zip.value
        }

        if (user != 'True'){
            userFormData.name = form.name.value
            userFormData.email = form.email.value
        }

        var url = '/process_order/'
        fetch(url,{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'form':userFormData, 'shipping':shippingInfo})
        })

        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            alert('Transaction Completed');

            cart ={}
            document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"

            window.location.href = "{% url 'store' %}"
        })
         
    }

</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

The error was in my console. **This is the error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at submitFormData (http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/:207:36)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/:140:5
    at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:15659)
    at e.n.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:14716)
    at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:16040)
    at e.n.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:14716)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:15526
    at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:15659)
    at e.n.resolve (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:14716)
    at e.n.dispatch (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:16040)

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at Pr.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:71786)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:80160)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Ir.o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:80019)
    at Ir (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:80172)
    at Yr.u.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:84738)
    at Yr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:84858)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:91179
    at Function.e.try (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:18264)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:90976

Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at Pr.error (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:71786)
    at Array.<anonymous> (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:80160)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Ir.o (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:80019)
    at Ir (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:80172)
    at Yr.u.on (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:84738)
    at Yr (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:84858)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:91179
    at Function.e.try (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:18264)
    at https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AVESrMsFLVbGdGrS_eWIIpWsK0Yu-W0_3kWU64V7t6LhL8mlMtduwiMZ4bt4yusZLInbf_Q7_64b0oAi&currency=USD:2:90976
```

It was saying that there's an error in my `submitFormData()` or JavaScript. But I cannot find what is the problem.

Comment: The value you're assigning to `user` is `request.user.is_authenticated`. Is that going to be a boolean?

Comment: I suspect form.name maybe rename the JS and HTML to fullName see if it works

Comment: Yup. In my if statements, I only use True or False to identify if the user is an authenticated one or an AnonymousUser.

Comment: It doesn't work @ZachJensz. I think the user-info form doesn't affect the process at all because I am login to an account right now.

Comment: This is so much easier to debug yourself on your end than with the information provided in the question. It's literally giving you the line number of where the undefined variable is in the JS being run by your browser.

Comment: @PrestonPHX I tried to explore the error and tried some debugging. The error was pointed in the var userFormData (specifically in the email. It was throwing undefined, why is that? How can I make it not undefined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057610/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null)

Comment: @HewrChelsea I tried every possible answer from that but still didn't solved the problem.

Comment: I was getting this exact error over the weekend on my own React project.  Tried like the devil to corner it, but failed.  It seems harmless.

Then, today, I was at a different site, opened the debugger to do some arithmetic, and they were having the same error on the console, 2x/sec.  Also a React app.  This is with 
Chrome Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (x86_64).  So, my guess is it's a Chrome bug.  Now, I'm ignoring it.